# WPML - Почему при создании записи через функцию сбрасывается перевод?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

У меня есть сайт на WordPress, в котором установлен плагин мультиязычности WPML. Мой исходный язык сайта - русский. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы выбранный язык пользователей сохранялся в cookie. Это нужно для того, чтобы при повторном входе на сайт - у пользователя сразу открывался язык который он ранее выбирал.

Для этого в header.php после  я добавил следующую функцию:

```
<?php 
$default_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_default_language', null );
if($default_lang!= ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
    setcookie('language', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, time() + 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']!= ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
        setcookie('language', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, time() + 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
    else {
      $wpml_permalink = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', get_the_permalink() , $_COOKIE['language'] );
      if(isset($wpml_permalink)) {
        wp_redirect( $wpml_permalink );
        exit;
      }
    }
} ?>
```

Она отлично работает. Если я выбираю Английский язык, у меня открывается ссылка site.ru/en. Если в будущем я повторно захожу на сайт по прямой ссылке site.ru - у меня автоматически открывается site.ru/en, то что мне и нужно.

Но есть одна проблема, которую я не могу решить.

В function.php у меня есть такая функция:

```
// Обработка отправки формы и создание записи
function my_custom_form_submit_handler() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['currency_export'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'my_custom_form_nonce' ) ) {
        $imaile = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['uemail'] );
        $single_ot = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['currency_export'] );
        $single_po = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['currency_export2'] );
        $single_wallet = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['mywallet'] );
        $single_val_op = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wallet_ot'] );
        $single_val_po = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wallet_po'] );
        $single_num = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['single_num'] );
        $single_val_minop = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wallet_minot'] ); // получаем значение из поля wallet_minot
        // $user_requisites = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wallet_reqot'] ); // получаем значение из поля wallet_reqot
        $single_val_minpo = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['wallet_minpo'] ); // получаем значение из поля wallet_minpo

        $post_data = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $imaile ),
            'post_content'  => '',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'     => 'post'
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

        if ( $post_id ) {
            // Сохраняем значения всех полей ACF
            update_field( 'single_ot', $single_ot, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_po', $single_po, $post_id );
            update_field( 'user_requisites', $single_wallet, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_mail',$imaile, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_val_op', $single_val_op, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_val_po', $single_val_po, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_num', $single_num, $post_id );
            update_field( 'single_val_minop', $single_val_minop, $post_id ); // сохраняем значение из поля wallet_minot в поле ACF single_val_minop
            // update_field( 'mywallet', $user_requisites, $post_id ); // сохраняем значение из поля wallet_reqot в поле ACF user_requisites
            update_field( 'single_val_minpo', $single_val_minpo, $post_id ); // сохраняем значение из поля wallet_minpo в поле ACF single_val_minpo

            // Отправляем письмо на указанный адрес
            send_email_notification( $post_id, $imaile, $single_ot, $single_po, $single_wallet );

            // Перенаправляем пользователя на страницу созданной записи
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_post_my_custom_form_submit', 'my_custom_form_submit_handler' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_custom_form_submit', 'my_custom_form_submit_handler' );
```

С помощью неё я могу создать запись через форму на сайте и у меня произойдёт редирект на эту запись. Проблема заключается в том, что при переадресации на созданную запись мой выбранный язык меняется на стандартный. У меня есть подозрение, что это связано с самими настройками WPML.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Каким образом можно сохранять язык при переадресации на запись? Буду крайне признателен за любую помощь, уже несколько дней пытаюсь решить эту проблему :(

Comment: Почему-то при любых вариациях запись создаётся исключительно на русском языке

Comment: *Почему-то при любых вариациях запись создаётся исключительно на русском языке*  - очень возможно, что связанно это с тем, что для неё (записи этой новой) не создано соответствие на других языках (а по умолчанию используется русский язык). То есть если бы были варианты этой страницы, предназначенные для отображения на тех языках (неважно с переводом или без), которые использует пользователь, то было бы всё нормально. К сожалению, не помню, есть ли там настройка по типу "Пытаться автоматически перевести страницу на текущий язык пользователя". Что есть...

Comment: WPML и так устанавливает куки языка, доп. не нужны. А проблема скорее всего в том, что ты не указываешь на каком языке создавать запись (и создаётся на основном).+ В настройках WPML установлена переадресация при несуществующей яз.версии. И это совсем не те настройки, что у тебя на скрине. https://i.imgur.com/f3JIPpz.jpeg

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению проблема актуальна если использовать любую функцию редиректа. Ко мне в голову пришла идея сделать промежуточную страницу между записью и формой. Т.е. чтобы после отправки формы создавалась запись, открывалась промежуточная страница (page-redirect.php), в которую передавалась ссылка. И далее уже происходил переход к записи. Но даже промежуточная страница, не смотря на то что у неё есть все варианты перевода, при использовании функции редиректа открывает исходный язык. Вот такие пироги :(

Comment: В настройках WPML->Languages есть чекбокс Language filtering for AJAX operations. Надо его активировать, и тогда WPML сам ставит куку текущего языка wp-wpml_current_language.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, решил свой вопрос с помощью костыля.

Внутрь формы вставляем скрытый input, в котором будет определяться текущий язык:

```
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; ?>">
```

Далее меняем функцию редиректа на это:

```
$lang = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['language'] );

// Перенаправляем пользователя на страницу созданной записи с добавлением параметра языка
wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'lang' => $lang ), get_permalink( $post_id ) ) );
exit;
```